# jquery sortable cancel remove based on confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to cancel sortable on the remove function if the response to a confirmation box is negative.  Here is my sortable unordered list.

```
$("#items").sortable({
    remove: function(event, ui) {  
      var id = ui.item.attr("id");
      var loadUrl = "LoadItem.action";
      var removeUrl = "RemoveItem.action";

      $.getJSON(loadUrl, {"id":id}, function(data){
        if (data.passed !== undefined){
          var answer = confirm("A status exists on this item.  Remove anyways?");
          if (!answer){
            $(this).sortable('cancel');  //<-- This is where I need help
            return false;
          }
          $.post(removeUrl, {"id":id}, function(){ 
            //alert('removed'); 
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

When I click cancel, it prevents my `$.post(removeUrl);` from firing as expected, but the line item still gets moved to the other sortable list.  I want it to cancel the line item move.  Using `$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');` in the receive event works this way, but is there a way to do the same thing in the remove event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#items").sortable({
  remove: function(event, ui) {  
  var id = ui.item.attr("id");
  var loadUrl = "LoadItem.action";
  var removeUrl = "RemoveItem.action";

  var self = this;
  $.getJSON(loadUrl, {"id":id}, function(data){
    if (data.passed !== undefined){
      var answer = confirm("A status exists on this item.  Remove anyways?");
      if (!answer){
        $(self).sortable('cancel');
        return false;
      }
      $.post(removeUrl, {"id":id}, function(){ 
        //alert('removed'); 
      });
    }
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the assignment of self the first time, but now it is working properly.