# jQueryUI Sortable - cancel sort based on confirmation box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

First, I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alrimo/SHxe5/) to demonstrate the issues below.

```
$(function() {
$(".ui-sortable").sortable({
    opacity: 0.8,
    revert: 200,
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("#list1").sortable("option", "connectWith", "#list2");
$("#list2").sortable("option", "connectWith", "#list1");

$(".ui-sortable").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {

    var answer = confirm("Move item?");
    if (!answer) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        return false;
    }

    var origZoneId = ui.sender.attr("id");
    var dockId = ui.item.attr("id");   
    var destZoneId = event.target.id;

    alert("Moving to: " + destZoneId + "From: " + origZoneId);

  });
});
```

My question is similar to the [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013283/jquery-sortable-cancel-remove-based-on-confirmation), however when implementing the answer I found that `receive` event was still being fired and I wanted  to prevent this, so I moved the confirmation box to the `receive` event.  All works fine except when:

*Steps*:

- Move an item from List 1 to List 2
- Move the item back to List 1, but select 'Cancel'.

  *Current output*:  Item stays in List 1

  *Expected output*: item moves back to List 2

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can avoid it?  I thought of moving the confirmation box back to 'remove' event and setting a flag, but this didn't seem very clean to me.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning `false`. which seems to be halting internal processes.

From the [cancel events](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) documentation:

> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state prior to when the current sort was started. Useful in the stop and receive callback functions.

There is no need to return `false`,  You can add the remaining code in an `else` part instead.

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/SHxe5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I add this in the sortable constructor

```
$( ".js-table-sortable" ).sortable(
    { 
        stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            var resp = confirm("Are you sure?");

            if(!resp){
                return false;
            }

        }
   });
```

this change cancel the sort option and return the dragged row to it's position.